# HAL_UART_Receive_DMA works only once. How can I fix it?

Tags: stm32, uart, dma, stm32f1, stm32cubemx

I am working with STM32F103RB board and I want to simply echo everything I receive from my computer via serial port back to that port. I must do it using UART and DMA. I've set up DMA on USART2_RX with CubeMX in normal mode. My problem is that `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` gets called only once. Interestingly I get the response on PC end but with additional `0xFC` byte. After that the controller stops reacting to new data sent through the serial port and won't do so until I unplug and plug controller back in with usb. Here is the code for call back and main function:

```c
#define BUF_SIZE 16

uint8_t RX_BUF[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
uint8_t TX_BUF[BUF_SIZE] = {0};

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, RX_BUF, BUF_SIZE, 1000);
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, RX_BUF, BUF_SIZE);
}

int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, RX_BUF, sizeof (RX_BUF));
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Edit: I am trying to do this on a Mac through USB-C dongle. Can this be the problem?

Comment: Looks like "interrupt flags not cleared" situation to me. I'd first check if after transmission/before new transmission all USART and DMA flags are reset.

Answer (score 1):

Calling complex functions in an ISR is a bad idea. Many of the HAL functions use the system tick to measure timeouts, and depending on your interrupt priorities, the tick may be blocked while your ISR runs.

It would be better to move any complex processing out of your ISR, into the main function. Just set a flag in the ISR to indicate when reception is complete. Something like:

```
static volatile bool uart_rx_done = false;

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    uart_rx_done = true;
}

int main()
{
    // Initialisation stuff

    for (;;)
    {
        uart_rx_done = false;
        HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, RX_BUF, BUF_SIZE);
        while (!uart_rx_done)
            ;

        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, RX_BUF, BUF_SIZE, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem. I tried both this solution and transmitting in ISR with DMA, but it had no effect.

Comment: Can you add to your post the definitions of RX_BUF and BUF_SIZE?

Comment: I updated the code. they are a uint8_t array of fixed size and a macro respectively.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if you configured `uart` and `dma` interrupts correctly.
in the `stm21f1xx_it.c` file you should see these functions

```
void DMA1_Channel6_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA1_Channel6_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA1_Channel6_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_usart2_rx);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA1_Channel6_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA1_Channel6_IRQn 1 */
}


void USART2_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart2);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_IRQn 1 */
}
```

and also a `uart2` configuration in the `MX_NVIC_Init()` function in your `main.c` file.

But your main mistake is that you're not activating `uart` receive interrupt at all. I suggest not using `dma` for now, and try this to see if the `uart` interrupt gets activated:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 16
bool uart_received = false;

uint8_t RX_BUF[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
uint8_t TX_BUF[BUF_SIZE] = {0};

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  // HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, RX_BUF, BUF_SIZE, 1000);
  uart_received = true;
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, RX_BUF, BUF_SIZE);
}

int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  //HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart2, RX_BUF, sizeof (RX_BUF));
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, RX_BUF, BUF_SIZE);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      if (uart_received) {
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, RX_BUF, BUF_SIZE, 1000);
          uart_received = false;
      }
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

If this works, then you can use `HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA` for activating `uart-dma` interrupt and `HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback` for callback function (assuming the `dam` interrupt is configured).